# corodova-cli 5.4.0 does not update metadata information in cordova_plugin.js

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

cordova-cli@5.4.0 is not updating the metadata information on the cordova_plugin.js file. Because of this ng-cordova Oauth plugin stopped working(Could not find inappbrowser). ng-cordova Oauth plugin uses this metadata information in the cordova_plugin.js file to check whether the inAppBrowser plugin is installed or not. I installed 5.3.3 to get rid of this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been reported as a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9976). Have you tried removing adding back your plugins? That's been suggested as a work around.